# Delete all characters after a backslash in python?

Tags: python

I have a for loop that changes the string current_part.
Current_part should have a format of 1234 but sometimes it has the format of 1234/gg

Other formats exist but in all of them, anything after the backlash need to be deleted.

I found a similar example below so I tried it but it didn't work. How can I fix this? Thanks

`current_part =  re.sub(r"\B\\\w+", "", str(current_part))`

Comment: You say *backslash* but you write /. Are we talking about a slash or a backslash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regexes here, why don't you simply go for `current_part = current_part.split('/')[0]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Find the position of '/' and replace your string with all characters preceding '/'

```
st = "12345/gg"
n = st.find('/');
st = st[:n]
print(st)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string using `string.split()`

for example:

```
new_string = current_part.split("/")[0]
```